# Fetching an array of document objects with different IDs from a document

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to show only documents from users in which the session user is subscribed to (in mongo using mongoose). The subscribed users are added to a 'following' array inside the user document. The user can only see objects (posts) from that array.

I am using node express. Here is the attempt using the populate method from mongoose.

```
    var user = req.user;
    var posts = [];
    Post.populate(posts, {path: "post.creator", match: {'creator': user.following}}, function (err, posts) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      posts.forEach(function (post) {
        posts.push(post);
      });
      console.log(posts);
      return res.render('subscribed', {posts: posts, user: user});
    });
```

I am new to mongoose, and have only been fetching bulk documents with no queries up until now.

The user model is made up as such:

```
//required stuff and set up 
...
//user object
var UserSchema = Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  posts: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }],
  following: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  followers: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
)}
//exports etc
...
```

And the post schema

```
//required stuff and set up
...
//post object
var PostSchema = Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
//exports etc
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I can see without going deep, you're using the same var posts with different scopes, I don't know what are you doing with posts out of the populate callback. Change the variables, because you are pushing data to the same returned object by de populate callback.

Comment: If you want to make a query and user.following is an array of ids, you can use the $in operator  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Donflopez, that was what I was looking for!